# How to get parameters of a table column in a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Good Evening, how to get the parameters of the `chk_group` input inside a servlet using `request.getParameterValues` here's the jsp form:

```
    <form name="MainForm" action="DeleteServlet" method="GET">
    <table BORDER=2 BORDERCOLOR=YELLOW width="120px" id="product_table">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><b>CarId</b></td>
            <td><b>Description</b></td>
            <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
            <td><b>Price</b></td>
            <td><b>CC.No</b></td>
            <td><b>Engine</b></td>
            <td><b>Cylinder.No</b></td>
            <td><b>MaxSpeed</b></td>
            <td><b>PetrolType</b></td>
            <td><b>PetrolCapacity</b></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${product_list}" var="car">
            <tr>
                <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk_group" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.carId}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.carDesc}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.quantity}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.price}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.enginCc}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.trans}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.noOfCylinder}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.topSpeed}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.fuelType}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${car.fuelCapacity}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Note:for each checkbox i only set the value when its checked with the value of the corresponding carId value:

```
function setCheckBoxValue(tableID) {
    try {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for ( var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];

            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                var carId = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
                table.rows[i].cells[0].value = carId;

            }

        }

    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your actual approach is a very bad idea, you should populate the checkbox value when rendering them (what would be the difference?). Even if using this JavaScript function, remember to execute it before submitting the form to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a checkbox value. When this form is submitted, you end up receiving an empty string as checked value. You need to give the checkbox an unique value so that you can uniquely identify the checked row. As for every other HTML input element, the checkbox value becomes the request parameter value.

E.g., the car ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="${car.carId}" />
```

Comment: I believe you didn't understood my answer. Get rid of that nonsensicial JavaScript approach and change your `<input>` with my exact `<input>`. That's all. This way the `request.getParameterValues("chk_group")` should return the desired values.